# #define macro doesn't as expect

Tags: c++

I got this problem wrong on a test and am really confused why.

For the given code below, I thought that the output would be 0. Can someone please explain why it isn't?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A 0
#define B A+1
#define C 1-B

int main{
    cout<<C;
    return(0);
}
```

The correct answer (and real output) is 2.

Answer (score 7):

You will get the correct answer if you expand the macros step by step.

```
cout<<C;
```

is

```
cout<<1-B;
```

is

```
cout<<1-A+1;
```

is

```
cout<<1-0+1;
```

which is

```
cout << 2;
```

Remember that macros don't work like variables. If you use variables you will get a different answer.

```
int a = 0;
int b = a+1;  // b is 1.
int c = 1-b;  // c is 0
cout << c;    // Expect 0 in output.
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor expands macros by doing text substitution, and producing code that is then compiled.   The preprocessor (mostly) does not understand expressions - that is handled by a later phase of compilation (after the preprocessor is done).

So `C` expands to `1-B` which expands `1-A+1` which expands to `1-0+1`.

This is treated by the compiler as an expression.  `1-0+1` gives `2`

To get the result (zero) that you expect, you need to use

```
#define A 0
#define B (A+1)
#define C (1-B)
```

so `C` expands to `(1-B)` which expands `(1-(A+1))` which expands to `(1-(0+1))`, which is evaluated (by the compiler, not the preprocessor) as an expression and gives `0`.

Bear in mind that `A`, `B`, and `C` are not variables.   They are macros - i.e. directions to the preprocessor on how to do text substitution.

Comment: Preprocessing substitutes preprocessing tokens, not text. Among other things, this means adjacent text will not be combined into new tokens (without using `##`) and forming things that are not proper tokens with `##` may produce errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that the output would be 0. Can someone please explain why
>   it isn't?

Because `C` expands to `1-B`

Now, `B` expands to `A+1`.

Now, again, `A` expands to `0`

---

Filling the gaps:

Since `A` expanded to `0` then `B` gets replaced by `0+1`

And replacing `B` in the expression `1-B` then becomes `1-0+1`

```
  C = 1-B
//    ^^^
//      A+1
//      ^^^
//
//  = 1-0+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Macros are so C89, c++11 came with a better solution to do this at compile time: constexpr.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr auto A = 0;
constexpr auto B = A + 1;
constexpr auto C = 1 - B;

int main{
    cout<<C;
    return(0);
}
```

Advantages are: easier to use, as you know the syntax and behavior already. Undefined behavior ain't allowed, which makes this safer. And you can't have circular dependencies giving strange side effects, as it wouldn't compile otherwise.